# Phonegap: Received JSON data fails to display

Tags: android, cordova, formatting, jsonp

I'm trying to code a dynamic phonegap app that retrieves and format information from a live database.

I use jsonp to get data from a php service I coded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var output = $('#output');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/service.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            //data loaded
            $.each(data, function(c,comp){
                window.alert(comp.filter); // I added this just to check I was getting data correctly.
                var company = '<div class="project-post ' +comp.filter+ ' ">'
                        +'<img  src=" ' +comp.img+ ' ">'
                        +'<div class="hover-box">'
                            +'<div class="project-title">'
                                +'<div><a href="coupons.html?id='+comp.id+'" rel="external"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>'
                            +'</div></div></div>';

                    output.append(company);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            //error loading data
            output.text('Error loading data.');
        }
    });
});
```

My console doesn't display any errors, I've been trying to solve this for a long time. I have this in my config:

`<access origin="*" />`

Also I confirmed I was receiving data with `window.alert(comp.filter);` It's just not displaying at all, maybe something's wrong with my formatting but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue because of dom formating, the img tag is not closed correctly it should be like:

```
var company = '<div class="project-post ' +comp.filter+ ' ">' +'<img src=" ' +comp.img+ ' "/>' +'<div class="hover-box">' +'<div class="project-title">' +'<div><a href="coupons.html?id='+comp.id+'" rel="external"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>' +'</div></div></div>';
```

Also take care of your access policy to allow all urls, update your config.xml file with the following code:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: I have this in my config: `<access origin="*" />` . Also I confirmed I was receiving data with `window.alert(comp.filter);`  It's just not displaying at all, maybe something's wrong with my formatting but can't figure out what it is.